# Issue with executing a PHP error message from a separate file in a login form system

Tags: php, forms, variables, authentication

I am running PHP 5.5.3. Essentially I have a web page [djaccess.php] with a simple login form on it that is connected with a MySQL database (with one username and password currently located within it):

```
            <form action="login.php" method="POST" >
            <p>Username</p><input type="text" name="usernameInput" /><br />
            <p>Password</p><input type="password" name="passwordInput" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="buttonSubmit" value="Login to DJ Access" class="submitButton"/>

            <?php 
            include ('login.php');
            if($error){ ?><h2 class="error"> There was an issue with the form"</h2><?php } ?>

            <a href="#">Find out more about DJing</a>
        </form>
```

When a user enters the username and password in the form fields, and clicks the submit button, the PHP script that detects whether this username and password is correct is located in login.php:

```
// Variables to connect to database
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbusername = "root";
$dbpass = "";


// Database connection
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpass) or die("Could not connect to database");
$selected = mysql_select_db("boxlogin", $dbhandle);


// Variables to set POST username & password
$myusername = $_POST['usernameInput'];
$mypassword = $_POST['passwordInput'];


// Protection from SQL injections
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);


// Selecting the username and password in the database table, and comparing the form values to the database values
$query = "SELECT * FROM test WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";


// Querying the form entries with the database, and ensuring that the count is equal to '1'
$result = mysql_query($query);
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);


// Re-direct to loginsuccess.php
if($count == 1){

    $seconds = 18000 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date ("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location:loginsuccess.php");
} else {
    header("location:djaccess.php") && echo $error;
}

// Ends connection to MySQL
mysql_close();
?>
```

If a username enters the password and username correctly, he/ she is successfully directed to loginsuccess.php HOWEVER, my problem is this:

I have set a count in the login.php page that if the username and password match it is equal to '1' therefore relocating that user to the loginsuccess.php page, but if that count does not equal to '1' I want them to be located back to the djaccess.php page with an error message present underneath the form that states that a username or password is incorrect, however I am having problems implementing this.

I have tried to set a header:location in the login.php if the count does not equal to '1' along with an echo $error variable but this does not seem to work. Also for reference I am new to PHP so still trying to get my head around the syntax. My code above was taken from hours of research and tutorials, and I understand what I have written, but I am stuck on this particular problem.

Can anyone help?

Comment: && is a logical operator for conditional checking. IE if ($count == 1 && $anotherCount != 1). Not 'execute this and this'; You can however do header('location:djaccess.php?error=Your username and password did not match'); and then in djaccess.php use the $_GET superglobal to check for that error message

Comment: Ok cool I'll look in to that now. How would I be able to place that error message underneath a form? Would I place the $_GET PHP script after the </form> tag?

Comment: in djaccess.php yes you can. <form> yada yada inputs</form> <? if (isset($_GET['error'])) { echo $_GET['error']; } ?>

Comment: Ok this works, which is good, and I understand why it works... but my last question is can I apply a <h2> on to it? Or any other HTML element on to it for styling purposes?

Comment: Yes, you can do anything you want to  it! Trial and Error is the best friend of a developer

Comment: It's cool I worked it out! I specified the $_GET['error']; as a variable, then styled that variable. Thank you so much for your help though! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your redirect handling to pass a message to the djaccess.php file. You can't use && logical operators to 'append' an action.

```
// Re-direct to loginsuccess.php
if($count == 1){

    $seconds = 18000 + time();
    setcookie(loggedin, date ("F jS - g:i a"), $seconds);
    header("location:loginsuccess.php");
} else {
    // CHANGE THIS
    // header("location:djaccess.php") && echo $error;
    $error = "Your username and password do not match";
    header("location:djaccess.php?error=$error");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to not hand coding things and do your project in a PHP framework like Kohana, CodeIgniter or Laravel where all of those functions and features have already been developed for you.

Comment: Fantastic answer, progressed his code, got him past this error to move on with. +1

Comment: @Rottingham I see your point.  Your answer is good.  I wrote what I wrote because I started out coding all of the PHP features in my applications, but now that I've grown to using frameworks, and can bring in a 15-line, 1.5 hour-to-develop feature with one line of code in one minute, I love it, won't go back and recommend it to all beginner and novice PHP developers.  I edited my answer to try and make it so that it doesn't come across as snarky.

Comment: I am with you there, I use frameworks for most of my work too, (custom made) but we ALL learned to use and even make frameworks by first learning how to do it all by hand.

Comment: I gotta agreen with Rottingham here, I would rather learn to hand code first and then move on to frameworks. But I definitely appreciate the frameworks suggestions I will be taking a look at those!